# JQuery Collision Detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, collision

Not sure if I'm on the right track here, but I figured this should work:

```
    function collides(a, b) {
              return a.x < b.x + b.width &&
                a.x + a.width > b.x &&
                a.y < b.y + b.height &&
                a.y + a.height > b.y;
    }
    function handleCollisions() {
      $('#player').forEach(function(player) {
        $('#powerUp').forEach(function(powerup) {
          if(collides(player, powerup)) {
           $('#player').hide(); 
          }
        });
      });
    }    
    handleCollisions();
    }
```

Basically I have my player running around the game and the object at a fix position. When the player collides with the object he should disappear. I will provide a fiddle if needed but I figured that there is something visibly wrong with the code. Any suggestions?

Edit:

```
  function collides(a, b) {
              return a.offset() < b.offset() + b.width() &&
                a.offset() + a.width() > b.offset() &&
                a.position() < b.position() + b.height() &&
                a.position() + a.height() > b.position();
    }

    function handleCollisions() {
        if (collides($('#player'), $('#powerUp'))) {
           $('#player').append("<p>collided</p>"); // hide player onCollision
          }
    }    
    handleCollisions();
    }


`
```

Comment: You can only have one `#player` and one `#powerUp` in your game, since they're IDs, not classes. You can't have two things with the same ID.

Comment: I only have one of each. What could I use instead of the .forEach() function, I think that might be the problem?

Comment: If you only have one of each, why not just `if (collides($('#player'), $('#powerUp')))`? `forEach` loops through all of the selected elements, and that seems quite silly if there's only one.

Comment: Right thanks, it's still not working though. Let me post a fiddle.

Comment: Another problem might be that `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` don't exist... you're looking for `offset()` / `position()`, `width()`, and `height()`

Comment: Geez thank you! So something like my edit above?

Comment: `.offset().top` and `.offset().left`, not just `.offset()`,  but yeah, something like that should work.

Comment: thanks again, let me give that a try.

Comment: I'm lost at what to change where, should I specify the direction for the position as well?

Comment: The [jQuery docs for `offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) might help.

Comment: I'm beat... I apologize for this but It's still not working for me

`return a.offset().left < b.offset().top + b.width() &&
                a.offset().top + a.width() > b.offset().left &&
                a.position() < b.position() + b.height() &&
                a.position() + a.height() > b.position();`